# nextjs error handling - getting The above error occurred in the <RedirectErrorBoundary> component:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm getting a strange error in the next.js - my error bound is giving me an error that the exception is not caught, everything else seems to be working (my error renders and reset works):

`login.tsx`:

```
import {tryLogin} from '@/app/lib/auth';

export default async function Page() {
    "use server"

    return (
        <div className="max-w-md mx-auto bg-white rounded-xl shadow-md overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl">
            <div className="p-8">
                <div className="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm text-indigo-500 font-semibold text-center">Login
                    Required
                </div>
            </div>
            <form action={tryLogin} className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8">
                <div className="mb-4">
                    <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="username">
                        Username
                    </label>
                    <input
                        className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                        id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-6">
                    <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="password">
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <input
                        className="shadow appearance-none border border-red-500 rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                        id="password" type="password" placeholder="******************"/>
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <button
                        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                        type="submit">
                        Sign In
                    </button>
                    <a className="inline-block align-baseline font-bold text-sm text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-800"
                       href="#">
                        Forgot Password?
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    );
}
```

`error.tsx`:

```
'use client' // Error components must be Client Components

import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

export default function Error({
                                  error,
                                  reset,
                              }: {
    error: Error & { digest?: string }
    reset: () => void
}) {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("HERE:::" + error)
    }, [error])

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Login Failed</h2>

            <button
                className="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline mt-1"
                onClick={
                    // Attempt to recover by trying to re-render the segment
                    () => reset()
                }
            >
                Try again
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`auth.tsx`: (yes, it's throwing an error every time)

```
import 'server-only'

import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
export async function tryLogin(username: string, password: string){
    "use server"
    return new Promise<string>(
        (accept, reject) => {
            reject("Login failed")
            // if(new Date().getTime() % 2 === 0){
            //     // redirect("/")
            //     reject('DUMMY_TOKEN')
            // } else {
            //     reject('Login failed')
            // }
        }
    )
}
```

Browser console:

```
XHRPOST
http://localhost:3000/login
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 23ms]

Uncaught Error: Error: Login failed 4 react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1792:14
The above error occurred in the <RedirectErrorBoundary> component:

RedirectErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9
RedirectBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:24
NotFoundBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:62
LoadingBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:335:76
ErrorBoundaryHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:114:9
ErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:161:67
InnerScrollAndFocusHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:152:9
ScrollAndFocusHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:227:37
RenderFromTemplateContext@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:16:44
OuterLayoutRouter@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:354:209
InnerLayoutRouter@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:243:18
RedirectErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9
RedirectBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:24
NotFoundErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9
NotFoundBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:62
LoadingBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:335:76
ErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:161:67
InnerScrollAndFocusHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:152:9
ScrollAndFocusHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:227:37
RenderFromTemplateContext@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:16:44
OuterLayoutRouter@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:354:209
main
body
html
RedirectErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9
RedirectBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:24
NotFoundErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9
NotFoundBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:62
DevRootNotFoundBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:33:24
ReactDevOverlay@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:84:9
HotReload@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:307:37
Router@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:181:114
ErrorBoundaryHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:114:9
ErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:161:67
AppRouter@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:536:47
ServerRoot@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:129:24
RSCComponent
Root@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:145:24

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundaryHandler. app-index.js:33:21
HERE:::Error: Error: Login failed
```